# Internal Server Error with very simple python script

Tags: python, macos, apache, cgi

I'm new to python, and i'm trying to run a simple script (On a Mac if that's important).

Now, this code, gives me Internal Server Error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print 'hi'
```

But this one works like a charm (Only extra 'print' command):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print

print 'hi'
```

Any explanation? Thanks!

Update:

When I run this script from the Terminal everything is fine. But when I run it from the browser:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py
```

I get this error (And again, only if i'm not adding the extra print command).
I use Apache server of course.

Comment: What is the exact error stacktrace ?

Comment: I'm surprised you get an "internal server error" when running a simple script. I noticed the 'apache' tag but that doesn't say anything about the way you actually run your script...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Looks like you're running your script as a CGI-script</s> (your edit confirms that you're using CGI)

...and the initial (empty) `print` is required to signify the end of the headers.

Check your Apache's error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` probably) to see if it says '*Premature end of script headers*' ([more info here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html#troubleshoot)).

**EDIT**: a bit more explanation:

A CGI script in Apache is responsible for generating it's own HTTP response.

An HTTP response consists of a header block, *an empty line*, and the so-called *body* contents. Even though you should generate *some* headers, it's not mandatory to do so. However, you do need to output the empty line; Apache expects it to be there, and if it's not (or if you only output a body which can't be parsed as headers), Apache will generate an error.

That's why your first version didn't work, but your second did: adding the empty `print` added the required empty line that Apache was expecting.

This will also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-Type: text/html"  # header block
print "Vary: *"                  # also part of the header block
print "X-Test: hello world"      # this too is a header, but a made-up one
print                            # empty line
print "hi"                       # body
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I checked, and it says 'malformed header from script. Bad header=hi: test.py'. What does it mean?

Comment: That the script's output is not valid for CGI. It should output valid HTTP headers before its regular output.